# Get many data using Laravel Array

Tags: arrays, json, laravel

PHP code:

```
$firstData =array (
  '000' => array (
  '000' => array (
   0 => '{"code":"11101000000","postal":"3310000"}',
    ),
  ),
  '000' => array (
  '000' =>array (
  0 => '{"code":"11101001000","postal":"3310058"}',
    ),
  ),
  '000' => array (
  '000' => array (
  0 => '{"code":"11101002000","postal":"3310068"}',
    ),
  ),
  '000' => array (
  '000' => array (
  0 => '{"code":"11101035001","postal":"3310078"}',
    ),
 ),  
);
$array_from_json = json_decode($firstData['000']['000'][0], true);
echo( $array_from_json['postal']);
```

Output result :

- 3310078

I want to get like this.

- 3310000 3310058 3310068 3310078

Could you help me?

Comment: Looking at your array you're only going to have the last value because each item has the same key (`000`). You can test this by using `dd($firstData)`.

Comment: You need to change the key `000`

Comment: Was the repeated keys in the array intended? This will not allow you get the array values you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array is wrong. You have same keys in your top level array ( all of them is 000 ) and that's your problem. Try to change them like this :

```
$firstData =array (
  '1' => array (
      '000' => array (
            0 => '{"code":"11101000000","postal":"3310000"}',
        ),
    ),
  '2' => array (
      '000' =>array (
            0 => '{"code":"11101001000","postal":"3310058"}',
        ),
    ),
  '3' => array (
      '000' => array (
            0 => '{"code":"11101002000","postal":"3310068"}',
        ),
    ),
  '4' => array (
      '000' => array (
            0 => '{"code":"11101035001","postal":"3310078"}',
        ),
    ),  
);
```

Then you can access your postal fields :

```
foreach($firstData as $data) {
    $array_from_json = json_decode($data['000'][0], true);
    echo($array_from_json['postal']);
}
```